# i'm checking for solution to return n_value with a function without using pointers

Tags: c

[image: this is my program]this program return :
1 - if a == b in sign like +a == +b then return circular permutation of a and b.

---

2 - if a != b in sign like -a and +b then return a+b and a*b.

---

as you can see in the second condition i have to return 2 value so i did this using pointers as you can see in the code bellow. `

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    /* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
    //prototyping
    void result_Condition(float *pointer_a,float *pointer_b);
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        float a=0,b=0;
        printf("Enter the value of a : ");
        scanf("%f",&a);
        printf("Enter the value of b : ");
        scanf("%f",&b);
        result_Condition(&a,&b);
        return 0;
    }
    
    void result_Condition(float *pointer_a,float *pointer_b) {
    if(((*pointer_a>0)&&(*pointer_b>0))||((*pointer_a<0)&&(*pointer_b<0))) {
    float tomp;
    tomp = *pointer_a;
    *pointer_a = *pointer_b;
    *pointer_b = tomp;
    printf("The value of a is : %.2f\n",*pointer_a);
    printf("The value of b is : %.2f\n",*pointer_b);
    }
    if((*pointer_a>0)&&(*pointer_b<0)||(*pointer_a<0)||(*pointer_b>0)) {
    *pointer_a = *pointer_a + *pointer_b;
    *pointer_b = *pointer_b * (*pointer_a-*pointer_b);
    printf("The sum of a + b is : %.2f\n",*pointer_a);
    printf("The prod of a * b is : %.2f\n",*pointer_b);
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hello, check if there is any solution to return multiple value using a function.

Comment: Please do not post images when you can include it as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a structure :

```
struct Result {
    float a;
    float b;
};

struct Result result_Condition(float a, float b) 
{
    // Do what you need to do then return the two values as a structure
    return (struct Result){ a, b };
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float a=0,b=0;
    
    // Get your values and use them
    struct Result r = result_Condition(a, b);
    printf("The value of a is : %.2f\n", r.a);
    printf("The value of b is : %.2f\n", r.b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you soo much i didn't know that you can return n_values using struct data types.